# Reactivate stored pid of a window with xdotool

Tags: shell-script, xdotool

First, I store the `pid` of an **active** window.

```
active_window_pid=$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowpid)
```

Second, I click on **another** window, which is actually function below.

```
mouse_click     4000 1000
```

Third, I want to reactivate the **previously active** window, sadly unsuccessfully.

```
xdotool search --pid $active_window_pid windowactivate
```

`function mouse_click`

```
    function mouse_click {

            # 1. activate window and wait for sync,
            #    we need to do this before each click,
            #    because the user may have clicked on some other window during the 2 second delay
            # 2. move the mouse cursor to the given position and wait for sync
            # 3. click the left mouse button
            # 4. restore the original mouse cursor position and wait for sync
            # 5. wait for 2 seconds

            xdotool         search --name "window name" windowactivate --sync

            xdotool         mousemove --sync $1 $2 \
                            click 1 \
                            mousemove --sync restore \
                            sleep 2

    }
```

What did I do wrong this time? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in `xdotool` in some versions at least.

bug string:

> Can't consume 1 args; are only 0 available. This is a bug.

bug tracker:
https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/14

bug workaround:
set `--name "whatever"`

```
function activate_window_via_pid {

    # for the chrome browser there are multiple processes,
    # therefore we must pick one of them,
    # the last one seems to work

    window_id=$(xdotool search --pid $1 --name "bug workaround" | tail -1)

    xdotool windowactivate --sync $window_id

}
```